# React Bootstrap Refusing to Render

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using React-Bootstrap to render a button group as an example, but it's refusing to render, and is instead telling me "ButtonGroup is undefined". I've installed the module via NPM and have imported it using ES6 (translated by babel). I'm exporting my components, to then eventually be rendered in my app as children.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import Bootstrap from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class NavBar extends Component {
    render(){

    return(
     <Bootstrap.ButtonGroup>
    <Bootstrap.Button>1</Bootstrap.Button>
    <Bootstrap.Button>2</Bootstrap.Button>
    <Bootstrap.DropdownButton title="Dropdown" id="bg-nested-dropdown">
      <Bootstrap.MenuItem eventKey="1">Dropdown link</Bootstrap.MenuItem>
      <Bootstrap.MenuItem eventKey="2">Dropdown link</Bootstrap.MenuItem>
    </Bootstrap.DropdownButton>
  </Bootstrap.ButtonGroup>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a special way to import using ES6 based on the docs for 'react-bootstrap':

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html#es6

> Es6 modules aren't supported natively yet, but you can use the syntax
>   now with the help of a transpiler like Babel.

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button';
// or
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

Answer (score 0):

you also will want to bring in ButtonGroup from the react-bootstrap library like this.

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button';
import ButtonGroup from 'react-bootstrap/lib/ButtonGroup';
// or
import { Button, ButtonGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';
```